# why is this code showing runtime error when trying to take input in the for loop?

Tags: python, numpy

why am I not able to take the input in the list   (line number 4) //a = int(input())

```
import numpy
mylist = []
for i in range(0,10):
    a = int(input()) 
    mylist.append(a)
arr = numpy.array(mylist,int) 
myreshaped = arr.reshape(3,3)
print(myreshaped)
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to reshape an array of 10 values into a 3x3 matrix (9 values).

Comment: You also need to convert the list into a numpy array first.

Comment: @PeterCollingridge ya you are right ,but i need help with the input values in for loop

Comment: The nice thing about error messages is that they tell you what the problem is and on which line it occurred.

Answer (score 0):

The only issue with your code is that you're trying to reshape an array with 10 elements into `(3,3)`. Try with `(10,1)` or `(5,2)` or one of these combinations and the code will run.

```
import numpy
mylist = []
for i in range(0,10):
    a = int(input()) 
    mylist.append(a)
arr = numpy.array(mylist,int) 
myreshaped = arr.reshape(5,2)
print(myreshaped)
```

Alternatively, you can create an array with 9 elements by changing the value in range function to `range(9)` or `range(1,10)`.

```
import numpy
mylist = []
for i in range(1,10):
    a = int(input()) 
    mylist.append(a)
arr = numpy.array(mylist,int) 
myreshaped = arr.reshape(3,3)
print(myreshaped)
```